# Support: How to go straight to cases-list on a client org? How to clone cases?

Tags: support, help, user-interface

Today I noticed a change in the Help&Training section. Last Friday (2015-10-23) it was more Aloha now it looks more Lightning.

But... the clickpath to the cases list is very long and time consuming. It wasn't straight-forward earlier, but it became way worse now. I want to go straight here:

[image]

As an unfortunate using a bookmark on https://help.salesforce.com/mysuccesshub?id=solutionFinder pipes me again to multiple clicktrough-pages and cost me time, even if I'm logged in already.

**Extension 1**

Additionally last Friday (2015-10-23) I had a "Clone" Button on the case-detail view. Now this is gone... The clone-button was very useful, since I have to log a lot of Cases for premier support (about Lightning Development, Bugs, etc.) and to fill out the long list is unnecessarily time consuming, because I use always the same Sandbox, OrgId, Browser, Browser-Version and I have provided login access...

**Extension 2**

It became very uncomfortable to log new cases, too. Before that "update" there was a "New Case" Button, which is gone! Now it looks like we have to click through the "Contact Us" in the right sidebar. Not nice...

**Extension 3**

Browser's forward/backward-navigation seems broken. You can't get reliably back and ahead, instead it will jump to an unintended page. Very frustrating...

**Extension 4**

I have to funnel all my texts (which are considerably long) into such a tiny little popup. This is very hard to use:
[image]

**Conclusion**

Right now my case input- and management-time feels quadrupled - at least.

What am I doing wrong? How can I use the new interface so that it saves time instead of cost more time? I'm sure that I'm missing something.

*Sidenote: I think the reason behind some of these issues is the Lightning way of navigation done by Javascript and events...  It looks like it comes at the cost that you loose a lot of good basic browser features at this time.*

Answer (score 4):

The most direct way I found is using this URL https://help.salesforce.com/home and clicking on the user icon (top-right) and pick "My Cases". I think it's kind of hidden there.

[image]

In the meantime I received the following response from Salesforce support about the details (Extension 1-4)

> **Extension 1**
>
> The Help & Training Portal has being updated on October 23, 2015. In
>   the new Help & Training portal there is no button to clone cases.
>
> **Extension 2**
>
> When the customer needs help, by typing the topic you need more
>   information on, you will find suggested articles appear as you type
>   and once you search, you will be able to find the answer you are
>   looking for quickly from the resources across all of Salesforce. When
>   the customer still not finding an answer they can always find the
>   support by clicking on the option "Click Here" in the last step. You
>   can always chat with the support, ask your questions in the community,
>   log a case or call the support:
>   https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000001000
>
> **Extension 3**
>
> This is working as designed. This can be an idea to improve the Help &
>   Training portal, you can add this idea in the success community
>   website: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaSearch
>
> **Extension 4**
>
> This is working as designed. You can prepare your text first in word
>   or notepad and then you can copy paste in the Case description. Or you
>   can always add your information/images/files as an attachment to the
>   case. You open the case and in the middle you have an option to attach
>   a file.

**Conclusion**

It is "as designed". So as a result short time fixes or workarounds seems unlikely. We might need to estimate higher times for interaction in that system as before 2015-10-23.